# Linux bash - Add alias from script without source(-ing) the script

Tags: linux, bash, alias

Is it possible to write a script like

```
#!/bin/bash
alias foo="bar -options"
```

and get the alias added to the running shell without `source`(-ing) the script

```
source myscript
```

will work, but just

```
myscript
```

not. The alias is set in the subshell (process) but lost on exit script

Any possibilities to change the alias of the parent shell without `source`

Comment: I think the `$(echo 'alias foo=bar')` approach (where you could replace `echo` with some other complex command/script) in [your other question](http://superuser.com/questions/826712) is probably the only other option. But really, `source` is the right tool for the job here. I don't understand why you're so against using it.

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem.  If you explain why it is that you want to avoid `source` commands, you would likely get answers that are much more useful.

Comment: @DaoWen - thanks again, @John1024 - where is the XY - I just ask "if it is possible" - I would like to avoid ````source```` because the script I am working on has a lot of functions via -options. Therefore all functions are called without ````source```` and so I try to minimize errors in using the scripts. I do not prefer to call it sometimes ````myscript```` and sometimes ````source myscript````. So again question is: possible or not? Thanks for help.

Comment: @DoaWen what is not working is: ````$(echo 'alias foo="bar -option"')````- this is still the problem :-)

Comment: @TomFreudenberg The unix design philosophy is that children should __not__ be able to alter their parent's environment/aliases/etc.  If you have aliases that you want to share between scripts without sourcing unwanted parts of a script, the standard approach is to put those alias definitions in a separate file on their own and then have each script that wants them source that file.    Separately, would you clarify the statement: "has a lot of functions via -options".  What is meant by "-options"?

Comment: @John1024 - thanks for statement. I realized now by require to ````source```` the script. The script is something like a modular swiss-kniff (like git add, git submodule etc). For the commands ````myscript aliases```` and ````myscript unaliases```` I test that they were called by ````source```` or print an error message if not. Thanks all for feedback.